# Can't properly query UTF8 tables in psql

Tags: windows, postgresql, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to do a select on a UTF8 DB, but the Results do not contain proper UTF-8 characters.
This is for german characters like "ä", "ö", "ü"

screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwH6z.jpg

The client_encoding is set to UTF8.

CHCP is 850.

When I do 
    psql -c "ö" -d ...-U postgres
I get
    ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf6
    HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encodi
    ng expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

The Database is definetely UTF8, when I do the query in pgadmin it works properly.

How to do this right?

---Edit---
After setting the right encoding for the cmd the command is working, but the results still can't be stored in powershell variables / be exported via powershell. 
using \copy to perform the export and reading the file in again solves the problem.
`\copy (Select 'ö') To 'e:/test.csv' With CSV`

Comment: Looks like *your terminal* doesn't handle UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: How to fix this? It's the same in Powershell, which has no problems working with UTF8 Chars, aswell as my cmd.

Comment: @Denis changing charset doesn't help

Comment: If you do the same command interactively, instead of via `-c`, does it work then? Wondering if psql is failing to do argument encoding conversion on Windows.

Comment: No, it behaves just the same. I'm calling psql from within powershell / cmd and it does just the same.

Comment: Since your terminal is sending *windows-1252* or *iso-8859-1* encoded data to *psql* (as shown by your *ö* being encoded as `0xf6`), it might work if the `client_encoding` is one of those encodings. But this will limit your input to characters found in those encodings. [Have you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8) writing your query to a *utf-8* encoded file and letting *psql* read the query from that file instead?

Comment: @bzlm That wouldn't make much sense because the problem is how the result is being shown, not how to query the results. So i can query tables with special characters, but they're not being shown right

Comment: @user2213834 according to your question, you cannot psql.

Comment: @bzlm What do you mean? I never claimed to be an expert on this.. I tried to read from a sql file now. so i do psql -U ... -d ... -c "\i e:/sql.txt", this is a file containing "select ö" and is encoded in utf8. when i do this, i get an error like 
psql:E:/sql.txt:1: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »ï»¿Select«
ZEILE 1: ï»¿Select 'Ã¶';

Comment: when i encode to "utf8 without BOM" I get a result, but with wrong encoding again for the cmd i guess. when i encode in ANSI it works, too, but with another wrong char

Comment: @Craig Ringer
I was wrong, the query works when I do it interactively. so chcp is 850, default. i start psql and type select 'ö', and it works. but how can i retrieve this result for further use? would i need to export via psql itself or is there a possibility to get the result right, when calling psql with -c option?

Comment: @user2213834 If `client_encoding` is `utf-8` you must use the matching terminal code-page, `chcp 65001`. Read the link that's been automatically added to the top of your post.

Comment: @Craig Ringer
Yes, I've read about that. When starting psql it says console codepage is 850 and windows codepage is 1252. setting chcp to 65001 and client_encoding to utf8 causes more problems: when I try sending "select 'a';" for example i just get "not enough ram". when i try "select 'ö';" it shows \q and terminates psql. 
When I set chcp to 1252 and leave client_encoding as it is it works properly, in interactive mode and with the -c option. But then i have to use a different console font.
So this works now. Still my Script isn't working properly.. another encoding problem i guess :-)

Comment: So to make a powershell script with a select like "select 'ö';" statement work I can just add chcp 1252 to the script and it will show  the result on the console correctly. the file itself is ANSI encoded. using powershell's "| out-file" piping into a text file for the result returns an error
FEHLER:  ungÃ¼ltige Byte-Sequenz fÃ¼r Kodierung Â»UTF8Â«: 0xf6 0x27 0x3b
(Error: invalid byte sequence for encoding utf8)
and the console output is broken again. using "utf8 without bom" exports the result to file, but broken char and also broken char on console. which encoding "fits" codepage 1252?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ atm. i found where to set right charset now.. but still out-file not working

Comment: the error occurs as soon as i try to store the result in a variable

Comment: If you're going to use utf-8, use utf-8 consistently. That means input files must be utf-8, SQL sources must be utf-8, etc.

Comment: @Craig Ringer
Works now, script utf8 chcp 65001, db is utf8. but client_encoding is 1252, else it won't work. this is all very confusing

Comment: @user2213834 Welcome to the wonderful and insane world of text encodings. With that behaviour, I'm kind of wondering if your input isn't misencoded, actually.