# getting error invalid byte sequence for encoding

Tags: postgresql

I have table `raw_ca_dd`

When upload data into the table I get an error like:

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfb
\copy raw_ca_dd from 'dbo_CA_list.csv.dak' with delimiter ','  csv quote as '"'
```

I unable to find this error. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say your file is in a different encoding, like `iso-8859-15`, rather than `utf-8`, since `0xfb` is invalid utf-8, but is `û` in many of the ISO 8859 encodings. It could also be `๛`,
`ϋ`, 
`ű`,
`ћ`,
`ū` in various other ISO 8859 encodings. There are also a bunch of code-pages (eg cp1255) I didn't bother to check.

Find out what the correct encoding of your file is and specify it with the `encoding` parameter to the `copy` command, eg:

```
\copy raw_ca_dd from 'dbo_CA_list.csv.dak' with encoding 'iso-8859-1' delimiter ','  csv quote as '"'
```

Don't assume it's `iso-8850-15`. Find out the actual text encoding of the input file and use that.