# PgAdmin III, opening server status gives "invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8"

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, pgadmin

I have two Postgres 9.3 servers in synchronous replication.

I had needed to restart the slave in order to load a new `archive_cleanup_command` in the `recovery.conf`.

The server restarted correctly and it's now perfectly in sync with the master server.

But when I open "Server status" panel for the slave server in PgAdmin III (which executable is located on the master server), I get some errors like this:

`invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”` plus some hex codes

[image]

It might be because I put a tilde `~` in the `archive_cleanup_command`, but it didn't worked, then I removed it and the command worked correctly.

Maybe that `~` has been written somewhere and it's not a valid char... but I also deleted logs...

Log of the slave server has a lot of lines like the followings:

```
2015-02-13 11:11:32 CET ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”: 0xe8 0x20 0x73
2015-02-13 11:11:32 CET STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_file_read('pg_log/postgresql-2015-02-13_111038.log', 0, 50000)
```

Note that `postgresql-2015-02-13_111038.log` is the last log, the one from which I got these lines.

Comment: What do you have configuration parameter `lc_messages` set to? Also see [this french forum post](http://forums.postgresql.fr/viewtopic.php?id=1258) and [this bug report](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201009161112.o8GBCYak052654@wwwmaster.postgresql.org)

Comment: Also relevant to know: what OS are you running these databases on?

Comment: @harmic: stupid me, I opened this bounty on friday but this week i'm on vacations, so I currently have no access to the system. I'll let you know and open a new bounty if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried the answer to this probably relevant question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8?rq=1

Comment: @harmic: `lc_messages` is set to Italian_Italy.1252, which is probably wrong since databases have their default *collation* and *character type* set to English_United States.1252. Should I try to set `lc_messages` to English?

Comment: @Teejay I know it's an old thread but I guess you should try `Italian_Italy.UTF-8` instead.
By the way did you get rid of that popup?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that the locale setting `lc_messages` is set to an encoding that is different to the encoding of the database(s). As a result, some messages are being written into the log using Windows-1252 encoding, while when you try to use PgAdmin to view the log, it tries to interpret the file using UTF-8. Some of the byte sequences written in the log are not valid UTF-8, leading to the error.

In fact, the way in which different locales interact in postgresql can result in mixed encodings in the log file. There is a [Bug Report](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201009161112.o8GBCYak052654@wwwmaster.postgresql.org) on this, but it does not look like it has been resolved.

Probably the easiest way to resolve this is to set `lc_messages` to `English_United States.UTF-8`.

It would also be preferable to have `lc_messages` aligned across all of the databases on the server (or at least all using the same encoding).

Be sure to remove any existing log files as they will already contain the incorrect encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, are you sure that the correct value is `English_United States.UTF-8` ? Searching Google for `"English_United States.1252"` leads me to roughly 15**k** results, searching `"English_United States.UTF-8"` leads me to 5 only.

Comment: @Teejay '1252' specifies to use Windows-1252 encoding when writing the messages. Since reading the message via the database `pg_file_read` function expects UTF-8 encoding, that might not work. Although I suspect it may work because the subset of characters used in English (basically ASCII) are encoded the same in both encoding types.

Comment: That solved my exact same problem. It should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your postgresql.log corrupted as stated in the statement 'select pf_file_read ....'.

If you do a "touch" (after a backup of your log perhaps) on you server log, and reconnect, you'll not see this unicode error anymore and thus, you'll be able to use pgadmin III furthermore.

Comment: I don't see how a `touch` can ***un***corrupt a file... by the way I also tried to delete log entirely...