# Postgres "ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0" occurred while dumpimg csv

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I got

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0"

while dumpimg csv to table, no record was inserted in the table but size of table and database got increased. How does that happen and is there any way to reduce it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your sql script or your csv?

Comment: Have you seen this : -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8 ?

Comment: What text encoding is in the database in? `SHOW server_encoding;`. What text encoding is the CSV in? You might have to specify the CSV encoding or change `client_encoding`. If it's iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 then 0xa0 is a nonbreaking space.