# What type should I use to store emoji in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unicode, emoji

I am working with Postgres and newbie too,

I have to store the user's comment (like facebook comment) into database. probably I will use column type "text" to store the comment.

If in case the comment is mixed up with emojis (unicode), the text type is enough or I should use any other column type?

Comment: just `text` is fine.

Comment: I've got a `invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xed 0xb3 0xa9` even with a `text` type...

Comment: @DestyNova that appears to be a unicode error. Try specifying the encoding before your operation http://stackoverflow.com/a/23794054/845598

Comment: If you get this error while using PHP, don't forget tu use the "mb_" family string functions.

Answer (score 10):

The [TEXT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) "character" type should be fine as UTF-8, generally, is a supported [character set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html).

Comment: and how to store emogis on that table?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Emojis are just characters, just text, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji). For example,  `a`, `b`, `c`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ``, `‍♂️`, `` are all just characters.

Comment: So is `char(1)` good enough for a single emoji ?