# How do I *PROPERLY* check if a string has a "valid byte sequence" for UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I keep receiving e-mails that are so badly constructed by such incompetent people that it somehow bypasses the PHP check using ***mb_check_encoding***, and thus proceeds to the PostgreSQL INSERT query, which keeps logging this kind of stupid nonsense:

```
pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe4 0x72 0x20:
```

This has been going on for years and has driven me nearly insane.

I can't use PG function hacks. This check must be done in PHP code.

How do I ***correctly*** detect if a string contains "invalid byte sequence" in PHP so that I can reject the e-mail as malformed (or "heal" it so that it contains "valid byte sequence")?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57169746/1127933

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8)